# Having trouble summarising data in R studio

Tags: r

I have a data set of species and how many were observed, however when I try to take the average for each species, I get the mean for the individual observation, so nothing is changing.

Along the top row of my data are the species names, and going down the column underneath them is the count. I am trying to summarize this data so I may plot it, but rather than the mean of the entire column being taken, it just takes the mean of the individual observation.

[image: Here is part of my data]

```
grassData <- read.csv("Dykebooke.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
View(grassData)


summary.grass <- grassData %>% group_by(Cordgrass) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(Cordgrass), variance = var(Cordgrass))
  
summary.lavender <- grassData %>% group_by(Lavender) %>% 
  summarise(mean(Lavender), var(Lavender))
  
summary.goldenrod <- grassData %>% group_by(Goldenrod) %>%
  summarise(mean(Goldenrod), var(Goldenrod))
  
summary.crab <- grassData %>% group_by(Crab) %>%
  summarise(mean(Crab), var(Crab))
  
summary.iva <- grassData %>% group_by(Iva) %>%
  summarise(mean(Iva), var(Iva))
  
summary.grasshopper <- grassData %>% group_by(Grasshopper) %>%
  summarise(mean(Grasshopper), var(Grasshopper))
```

This is what I have done so far, but this is what it provides.

[image: Output]

I have not used R in a few years so I am very rusty, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: do you want to get the average elevation? average distance? by species]

Comment: I am looking to find the average occurrence of a species, each sample was taken every six feet, so I'm trying to find the average amount of the species by distance

Comment: How about using just `mean(grassData$Cordgrass)`?

Comment: mean(grassData$Cordgrass) seems to give me the appropriate numbers, however when I check my summary.grass, rather than only having a cell for the single mean and variance, I have 18 observations all with the same mean and variance. How could I turn that into just one?

Comment: I am also trying to plot my data after I get the mean and variance using ggplot, I got the code below to work, however it does not give me a plot but rather a list named p   p <- ggplot(summary.grass, aes(Elevation, Species)) +
+ 
+     geom_point() + facet_wrap(~group)